# Plotting on Matlab

Tags: roots, matlab, tangent-line

I'm trying to plot the curve shown below on Matlab. $y= x \, \tan x$ and $x$ is in the range $(0, 4 \, \pi)$. The thing is

1. I can't seem to multiply x with tan(x) without getting an error.
2. I just need intersecting points between tan curve and circle (forget the cot curves in picture for now).
   Any suggestions?
   [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2G4Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be Matlab because [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) does a pretty good job. See [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v3yf0nypxw) graph.[image]

Comment: Thank you. You're a life saver. God bless

Comment: For starters you can upvote and accept this answer.